# UTF-8 characters in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I want to use turkish charecters in my project but Turkish characters look like

> �

My Jade layout code like that

```
doctype html
html
    head
        meta(charset="UTF-8")
        meta(http-equiv="Content-Type",content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-9")
        meta(http-equiv="Content-Type",content="text/html;charset=windows-1254")
        meta(http-equiv="Content-Type",content="text/html;charset=x-mac-turkish")
        meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
```

Why I can not make this ?

Comment: change your file to UTF-8 encoding )

Comment: How ? Im sorry but I cant understand @Kolley

Comment: Open file in some redactor/IDE and check encoding with what you code.

Comment: What was that string _supposed_ to be?

Comment: @robertklep ,thats string would be ı and the others problems string like,ü ö Ö ç Ç ş Ş ğ Ğ İ ı

Comment: @Kolley Im use Web Storm how can I make that you say to me ?

Comment: Bottom right. There's dropdown list by click with encodings.

Comment: I wouldn't write in Turkish... Let's say in the future you want to sell it. Buyers will be put off by that fact. I would rather deal with grammar mistakes rather then paying a translator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your file to UTF-8 encoding ) – KoIIIeY 
For WebStorm users, you have come up with this problem when you select the URL option in the lower left or right corner and rebuild UTF-8 or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you don't have to add other metas other than `utf-8`:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        meta(charset="UTF-8")
        meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
```